# Having trouble when counting prime numbers between two integers

Tags: java

I'm having issues getting all prime numbers between a given integer A and integer B.

The issue is that the output goes well beyond whatever I defined for B. I thought that the

```java
if (isPrime){
    count++;
```

would fix this but the output still goes well beyond the intended number of integer B.

For example if `int valueA = 1` and `int valueB = 100`, it'll get prime numbers from around 1 to 500 before stopping, instead of just ending the check at 100.

Thank you for any assistance.

```
import java.util.*; 

public class PrimeNumbersTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

        // Ask user to input an integer value for A and B
        System.out.print("Enter the value of A (must be an integer): ");
        int valueA = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the value of B (must be an integer): ");
        int valueB = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The prime numbers between " + valueA + " and " + valueB + " are:");

        final int LINE = 10;
        int count = valueA;
        int number = 2;

        while (count < valueB) {
        // Assume the number is prime   
        boolean isPrime = true;
        // Test if number is prime
        for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= number / 2; divisor++) {
            if (number % divisor == 0) { // If true number is not prime
                isPrime = false; // Set isPrime to false
                break; // Exit the for loop
            }
        }
         if (isPrime) {
             count++;

            if (count % LINE == 0) {
                System.out.println(number);
            }
            else 
                System.out.print(number + " ");

         }
         number++;
    }      
  }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be getting the first B number of primes, not the primes up to B. Think about `if (isPrime) count++;` and `while (count < valueB) {` carefully. I think you want to be checking against `number`, not `count`.

Comment: Actually when I tried to replace count with numbers on while (count < valueB) it just always starts off at 2. So 1-100 would work, but if I input 10 on A and 100 on B it'd still start at 2.

I tried count++ on the bottom instead of number++ but that doesn't really make sense. Not sure why I'm struggling with the logic so much here

Comment: When you want to work on a range of number, use a for loop to reduce confusion. You obviously want `for(int number = valueA; number <= valueB; number++){/*check if number is prime*/}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to work on a range of number, use a for loop instead of while loop to reduce confusion. You obviously want

```
for(int number = valueA; number <= valueB; number++){/*check if number is prime*/}
```

Example:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    int valueA = 1;
    int valueB = 100;
    int count = 0;
    for(int number = valueA; number <= valueB; number++)
    {
        if(isPrime(number))
        {
            count++;
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("count = " + count);
}

public static boolean isPrime(int n)
{
    for(int i = 2; i*i <= n; i++)
    {
        if(n % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return n > 1;
}
```

For your requirement of checking isPrime inline:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    int valueA = 1;
    int valueB = 100;
    int count = 0;
    for(int number = valueA; number <= valueB; number++)
    {
        boolean isPrime = number > 1;
        for(int i = 2; i*i <= number; i++)
        {
            if(number % i == 0)
            {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isPrime)
        {
            count++;
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("count = " + count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

One of the issues is I do need the 


```
boolean isPrime = true;
  // Test if number is prime
  for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= number / 2; divisor++) {
   if (number % divisor == 0) { // If true number is not prime
    isPrime = false; // Set isPrime to false
    break; // Exit the for loop ```



For the program to be acceptable by my teacher. So I've had to work around that, and that's where I'm stuck. I've been trying to rework the program right now around that to no avail.

edit: not sure how to format code in replies

Comment: @DHazard just replace the isPrime function. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I'm trying to learn from what you just did, but yeah it can't be edited in anyway. I have to work around that part. So for example, I couldn't add i * i in the for loop part of your edit. I'm going to study your code and try to figure it out thanks

Comment: I actually ended up figuring out! Now might I ask, how do I end up adding 5 of those prime number results per line of output? It's giving me one by one and changing it to printf isn't helping

Comment: @DHazard You can print like this: `System.out.print(number + ((count % 5) == 0 ? "\n" : " " ));`